Set variable in Cmder's alias file, user_aliases.cmd
I want to create a variable in user_aliases.cmd for use later in the file, with Cmder under Git for Windows (with Clink). Windows 11.
I've read that this is the way to do it, but it's not working for me. I've tried several variations, but none have worked. The intention here is to have the spform alias change to the projects directory/spform. I have many aliases that could use the long path as a prefix. I've read that I could set this as an environment variable in Windows, but I'd rather have it be set temporarily when the Cmder terminal is running.
@set PROJECTSPATH=c:/xampp/htdocs/addons/assets/mycomponents;%PROJECTSPATH%

spform=cd %PROJECTSPATH%/spform

